# How to update ChartJS in a long polling & stop animation stuttering?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two issues when i'm trying to update my ChartJS values / datasets, the first is when a new dataset is added to chart datasets it's placed far from other bars (this happens when there are other datasets with zero values in it) in same dataset, another issue is that the data is not updated for same dataset when it's y value is chaged.

Here is what i've tried:

```js
let API = [{
    "totpag": 6.5,
    "descrpag": "CONTANTI",
    "data": "2022-02-15T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "totpag": 5.5,
    "descrpag": "POS MANUALE",
    "data": "2022-02-15T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "totpag": 25,
    "descrpag": "ASSEGNI",
    "data": "2022-02-15T10:00:00"
  }
]

const optionsPagamentiBar = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: 0,
      usePointStyle: true,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
         let y = context.parsed.y;
         if (y) {
          return context.dataset.label + ": " + "€" + context.parsed.y.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,').replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return "€" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        }
      },
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false,
        zeroLineColor: "transparent",
      }
    },
    x: {
      display: 1,
      ticks: {
        padding: 10,
        display: true,
        fontSize: 10
      },
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}


const chartBarPayments = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartBarPayments").getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
    }]
  },
  options: optionsPagamentiBar
});


let periodo = 'giorno'

function getColorsByLabels(labels) {
  //const colorScale = d3.interpolateSinebow;
  //const colorRangeInfo = {
  //    colorStart: 0.2,
  //    colorEnd: 1,
  //    useEndAsStart: true,
  //};
  //let COLORS = interpolateColors(labels.length, colorScale, colorRangeInfo);
  let COLORS = ["rgb(167, 3, 213)", "rgb(255, 64, 64)", "rgb(24, 114, 244)", "rgb(34, 0, 97)"]
  let backgroundColors = {};

  COLORS.forEach((color, index) => {
    backgroundColors[labels[index]] = color;
  })
  return backgroundColors;
}

function pagamentiPerFascia(pagamenti) {
    let datasets = [];
    let timePeriods = [];
    let datasetLabels = [];
    let indexedData = {};
    pagamenti.forEach((pagamento, i) => {
        let date = "";
        if (periodo == "anno") {
            date = moment(pagamento.data).format("MMM YYYY");
        } else if (periodo == "mese") {
            date = moment(pagamento.data).format("DD MMM");
        } else {
            date = moment(pagamento.data).format('HH:mm');
        }

        if (!timePeriods.includes(date)) {
            timePeriods.push(date);
        }
        if (!datasetLabels.includes(pagamento.descrpag)) {
            datasetLabels.push(pagamento.descrpag);
        }
        indexedData[pagamento.descrpag + date] = pagamento.totpag;
    })
    let backgroundColors = getColorsByLabels(datasetLabels);
    datasetLabels.forEach(label => {
        const dataset = {
            label,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColors[label],
            data: [],
            skipNull: true,
        };
        timePeriods.forEach(date => {
            dataset.data.push({
                x: date,
                y: indexedData[label + date] || null
            })
        })
        datasets.push(dataset);
    })


    updateChart(datasets)
}

function updateChart(datasets) {
    chartBarPayments.data = {};
    datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        // checking if dataset exists in chart
        let chartdataset = chartBarPayments.data.datasets.find((data) => data.label === dataset.label);
        if (chartdataset) {
            dataset.data.forEach((date) => {
                // checking if x value exists in chart dataset
                let chartdata = chartdataset.data.find((data) => data.x === date.x);
                if (chartdata) {
                    console.log("if", date.y)
                    // if x value exists i''m setting it with the new value (even if it's the same)
                    chartdata.y = date.y || null;
                    chartBarPayments.update();
                } else {
                    // else pushing a new xy value to data 
                    console.log("else", date.y)
                    chartdataset.data.push({
                        x: date.x,
                        y: date.y || null
                    })
                    chartBarPayments.update();
                }
            })
        } else {
            // if the dataset does not exists i'm pushing it as a new one
            chartBarPayments.data.datasets.push(dataset);
            chartBarPayments.update();
        }
    });
}

pagamentiPerFascia(API)

var longPolling = setInterval(() => {
  API[0].totpag = 15;
  API.push({
    "totpag": 16.5,
    "descrpag": "VISA",
    "data": "2022-02-15T10:00:00"
  });
    API.push({
    "totpag": 16.5,
    "descrpag": "VISA",
    "data": "2022-02-15T11:00:00"
  });
  
  pagamentiPerFascia(API)
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartBarPayments"></canvas>
```

How can i update the values and is there a way to hide zero values from the chart?

**UPDATE:**

Solved the issue with spacing between bars by setting `null` instead of `0` in empty bars and added `skipNull` to each dataset.

UPDATE 2:

Solved even the issue with value update by replacing

```
 chartData = date;
```

with

```
 chartData.y = date.y;
```

The main issue here is that i have to clear the .data every time which cause animation stuttering even when there is no new data, clearing data is needed as the dataset can change any time with all new Y labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation and I ended up disabling the animation, which obviously solved the problem, but because it looked a bit less dazzling the customer did not like the solution, in the end I had to utilise a hack.

Not sure if this will work for you, but in my case it did, you do this by using setTimeout to 1 millisecond.

Run the update & then set a timeout for a millisecond & run the update again. If this doesn't work, try setting arbitrary data (instead of emptying the data) & then updating to the correct dataset a millisecond later.

In my instance:

```js
refreshScope( endscope ) {
    if(this.current_scope == 'today') {
        this.current_scope = `week`; // Opposite (changes data on watcher)
    } else {
        this.current_scope = `today`; // Opposite again.
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.current_scope = `${endscope}`;
    }, 1);
}
```

There are of course other (better) options you can employ, as outlined by ChartJS' performance page:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.1.1/general/performance.html

And ultimately disabling animation will make it seem accurate - not stutter, albeit less dazzling, and not require hacks.

Disabling animation:

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        animation: false
    }
});
```